# How do I extract this HTML data using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How would I use beautiful soup to extract the number 13.4 and place it into a variable from the following HTML table extract? The bs4 package is installed and imported into my code, the HTML has been parsed using lxml, so I only need the command to extract the required data.

```
<tbody> <!-- abcd open history tbody after col headings -->
<tr class="rowleftcolumn">
<td headers="t1-datetime">06/01:30pm</td>
<td headers="t1-tmp">13.4</td>
<td headers="t1-apptmp">8.6</td>
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: `bs4` has nothing to do with `lxml` - literally every tutorial and example on the internet shows the basic "how to get a value". Can you share what you actually tried and didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken data as `html` and from it first find the base element from it and then we can use `find_all` method to find all `td` tag and extract from list using index

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""<tbody> <!-- abcd open history tbody after col headings -->
<tr class="rowleftcolumn">
<td headers="t1-datetime">06/01:30pm</td>
<td headers="t1-tmp">13.4</td>
<td headers="t1-apptmp">8.6</td>"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

main_tr=soup.find("tr",class_="rowleftcolumn")
temp=main_tr.find_all("td")[1].text
print(temp)
```

Output:

```
13.4
```